# NameError: name 'Bscs' is not defined

Tags: django, database, django-models

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrKGj.png)[please help me, I'm new to making table for database and I don't know how to fix this][2]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is short example for using ForeignKey

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.Category(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Try to read about many-to-one relationship
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/